# Specifying database connection string for EntityFramework6.Npgsql - Code First

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I have an issue regarding the .NET postgreSQL provider package `EntityFramework6.Npgsql`. I have installed the following packages: `EntityFramework 6.0.0, EntityFramework6.NpgSql 3.1.1, Npgsql 3.1.0`.

Currently I have just started a WPF project so I'm using a simple standard DbContext and it looks like this:

```
public class TimetrackerDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TimetrackerDbContext()
        : base("name=DbConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my `App.config` file I specify the connection string. I've been trying to use this connection:

```
<add name="DbConnection"
   connectionString="User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Host=xxx;Port=5432;Database=xxx;Pooling=true;"
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But when I run `enable-migrations -contexttypename MyDbContext` in the PM Console I get the following error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'user id'.
```

I tried specyfying the metadata, provider connection string but it also threw errors and it does not make much sense to use it in Code First. In case somebody it could be useful here's my whole `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"     type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0"         />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DbConnection"
   connectionString="User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Host=xxx;Port=5432;Database=xxx;Pooling=true;"
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `providerName` of your connection string `System.Data.EntityClient` is for Database First (edmx) type connections where the actual provider is encoded in the `connectionString` value.

For Code First connections, the `providerName` should match the `invariantName` from the `providers` section. In your case, replace

```
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

to

```
providerName="Npgsql"
```

Comment: Ok, that and upgrading Npgsql to `3.1.2` fixed the issue. Thanks!